# Custom Window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window, visual-studio-2022

How to create a class that inherits from the Window class.I want this class to have render in visual studio designer.

What I have
[image]

What I want
[image]

Only, as you can see, I will extend the standard class. And I would really like to see my visualization, instead of the standard one. But I don't even know how to approach it.

I would be very grateful if you could help me find a solution.

-- Changed

At the moment, all the layout is in the window class.

Window Source Code

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ApplicationViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Border Style="{StaticResource WindowBorderStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="10 0 0 10">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#223266" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#27396b" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <StackPanel>
                
                <!-- UserPanel -->
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 35 0 0" Content="{Binding UserViewModel}"/>
                <Separator Height="0.8" Margin="20 30" Background="#46558A"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MenuViewModel}"/>
                
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- Main page-->

        <Border Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0 10 10 0" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" >
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#41518f" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#2c386c" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Header -->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,5">
                    <cc:HeaderButton Icon="EyeSlash" IsEnabled="False" />
                    <cc:HeaderButton Icon="WindowMinimize" Command="{Binding MinimizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BaseWindow}"/>
                    <cc:HeaderButton Command="{Binding NormalizeOfMaximizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BaseWindow}">
                        <cc:HeaderButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type cc:HeaderButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="WindowMaximize"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="Maximized">
                                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="WindowRestore"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </cc:HeaderButton.Style>
                    </cc:HeaderButton>
                    <cc:HeaderButton Icon="WindowClose" Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BaseWindow}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MenuViewModel.SelectedMenuElement.ViewModel}"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

It seems to me that it would be right to share the responsibility.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Window chrome is not displayed in the designer because it's different on different versions of Windows.  You could hide the chrome and make your own using the grid, but if you are modifying the chrome directly, that will never show at design time.  You didn't show us any code so we can't really answer beyond that.